# Transmitting number as number through UART with STM32

Tags: c, stm32, uart

i'm new to microcontrollers, i want to send numbers as numbers through UART using STM32 NUCLEOL053.

my script is:

```
uint8_t nums[8] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7};

HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, nums, sizeof(nums), HAL_MAX_DELAY);
```

it does not work, how can i solve this? compiler tells me no error or warnings,
i already know how to send numbers as string using sprintf but i need to send numbers as numbers

Comment: "it does not work" is a pretty bad problem description

Comment: Yea sorry, compiler tells no errors and no warnings, when i start the program on the ide the terminal just shows anything even if the transmit function is inside the while(1) loop, on the terminal there's just the vertical bar for the text(pipe) that flashes more quickly than usually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try converting number in to ASCII and the call the function to transmit on UART.

```
uint8_t nums[8] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
char ascii_nums[8][5];

for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    itoa(nums[i], ascii_nums[i], 10); // convert the number to a string
}
```

Note: You need to use `for` loop to transmit the numbers one after the other.